# How to test Grails service using Spock?

Tags: java, unit-testing, grails, groovy, spock

I have a `EncouragementService.groovy` with following method

```
  class EncouragementService {
   def stripePaymentService 

   def encourageUsers(List<User> users){
     if(null != users && users.size()>0){
      for(User user : users){
        //logic
        stripePaymentService.encourage(user)
        //
      }
     }   
   }
  }
```

To test above code in JAVA universe, using JUnit I would first create two or three users in setup. Pass the list of users to `encourageUsers(...)` method and check whatever I want with the result.

How can I achieve the same thing here in grails,

```
import com.github.jmkgreen.morphia.Datastore;

@TestFor(EncouragementService)
class EncouragementServiceSpec {

  def morphiaService = new MorphiaService()

  void testEncourageUsers() {
        List<User> users = createUsers();
        encouragementService.(users)  
            //
  }

  def createUsers(){
       Datastore datastore = morphiaService.dataStoreInstance()
       def user = new User()
       user.setName("Prayag Upd")
       //
       datastore.save(user)
       [user]
  }
}
```

I am using [spock:0.7](https://code.google.com/p/spock/)

```
plugins {
    test(":spock:0.7") { exclude "spock-grails-support" }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Service class can be optimized as below:

```
class EncouragementService {
   def encourageUsers(List<User> users){
       if(users){ //Groovy truth takes care of all the checks
          for(user in users){
            //logic
          }
       }   
   }
}
```

Spock Unit Test:
Spock takes testing to whole another level, where you can test the behavior (adheres to BDD). The test class would look like:

```
import spock.lang.*

@TestFor(EncouragementService)
@Mock(User) //If you are accessing User domain object.
class EncouragementServiceSpec extends Specification{
  //def encouragementService //DO NOT NEED: mocked in @TestFor annotation

  void "test Encourage Users are properly handled"() {
      given: "List of Users"
          List<User> users = createUsers()

      when: "service is called"
          //"service" represents the grails service you are testing for
          service.encourageUsers(users) 

      then: "Expect something to happen"
          //Assertion goes here
  }

  private def createUsers(){
       return users //List<User>
  }
}
```

Comment: "Patience" is [my name](http://www.ask.com/question/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-name-dhiraj), I am not joking ;). Frankly speaking, recently I had a [presentation](http://dmahapatro.github.io/bdd-grails-spock-presentation/#/) on spock in local Grails User group, so I thought I would brag about something I worked on. ;) @SérgioMichels

Comment: @dmahapatro When `User` is not a `grails-app/domain` based entity, I get `Failure:  test Users are properly handled(np.zazzercode.service.EncouragementServiceSpec)
|  org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsConfigurationException: Cannot add Domain class [class np.zazzercode.domain.User]. It is not a Domain!
 at grails.test.mixin.domain.DomainClassUnitTestMixin.registerGrailsDomainClass(DomainClassUnitTestMixin.groovy:209)
`

Comment: @PrayagUpd Yea, if User is not a domain class, then you would not need `@Mock` that is what I meant in the answer.

Comment: @dmahapatro Ok got that, But how do I initialize a service(eg. `stripePaymentService`) used inside `EncouragementService`. Since that is not being injected, throws `java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method encourage() on null object` while testing app

Comment: @dmahapatro Well it's fixed adding `def stripePaymentService = Mock(StripePaymentService)
   service.stripePaymentService = stripePaymentService` to `given`

Comment: Also you need to mock the `encourage` method inside the stripePaymentService, right?

Comment: Yes, correct. `@TestFor` takes care of the current service class under test. But other services have to be mocked.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [build-test-data plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/build-test-data) to build the users.

```
@TestFor(EncouragementService)
@Build(User)
class EncouragementServiceSpec extends Specification {

  def "encourage users does x"() {
    given:
    def users = createUsers();

    when:
    service.encourageUsers(users)  

    then:
    // assert something
  }

  def createUsers(){
    [User.build(), User.build(), User.build()]
  }
}
```

I've also made a couple of changes to the code to make it a proper spock specification. Your test has to extend Specification and you might want to familiarize yourself with [Spock's keywords](https://code.google.com/p/spock/wiki/SpockBasics).

Comment: [build-test-data plugin](https://github.com/tednaleid/build-test-data) looks awesome, but doesn't seem to work for non `grails-app/domain` based entities. Throws exception `org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsConfigurationException: Cannot add Domain class [class np.zazzercode.domain.User]. It is not a Domain`